# Difference between := and ← in pseudocode

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

This is a snippet from some pseudocode for a sorting algorithm. In it, the symbol ← is used to denote assignment, for example for the variable `done`. However, in the `while` loop the statement `done:= false` is written. I would assume it is also an assignment statement but I suspect it means somethings else, or perhaps extra, since if not, the ← would have simple be used again.

```
Algorithm MyAlgorithm(A, n) 
    Input: Array of integer containing n elements 
    Output: Possibly modified Array A

done ← true 
j ← 0
while j ≤ n - 2 do
     if A[j] > A[j + 1] then
        swap(A[j], A[j + 1])
        done:= false
     j ← j + 1
```

Comment: This appears to be a slip-up in writing the code. At first I thought the arrow may denote "declare + define", whereas `:=` would denote "redefine", but it's clear that `j` is redefined using the arrow below. In general, `:=` is an assignment in pseudocode; to be honest, I've never seen the arrow in actual pseudocode.

Comment: @Eric You should put this as an answer, I think it's as much an answer as it gets.  However, I've seen `←` as assignment (and use it myself) quite a lot.  As long as people are consistent, it doesn't really matter much, as the given pseudocode obviously isn't.

Comment: @PålGD Posted it, with an extra reference to Wikipedia. It's worth noting that they do recognize both the arrow and `:=`, though they mention that `:=` is "more common".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The use of `:=` in this context appears to be a slip-up from whomever it is who wrote that pseudocode. The initial impression given is that they have different meanings (I thought at first that `:=` was perhaps "redefine", and that `←` was "declare and define"). However, with the use of `j ← j + 1` on the line following it, it seems clear that the `:=` was a mistake.

In general, `:=` and `=` are the most common assignment operators, seemingly in both pseudocode and real code. You may be interested in looking at [notations of the assignment operator in various programming languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_%28computer_science%29#Notation), which include `:=`, `=`, `<-`, `←`, and many others.